# How to use jsdoc's @mixes for ES6 classes in combination with WebStorm

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc

Using JSDoc's `@mixin` for objects, I can write something like this:

```
/**
* @mixin foo
*/
const foo = {
  myMethod() {}
}

/**
* @mixes foo
*/
const bar = {

}
```

and my WebStorm IDE shows that `bar` has a `myMethod` method. I like to use the `@mixin` decorator from core-decorators to mix in some objects in my class:

```
/*
* @mixes foo
*/
@mixin (foo)
class bam {

}
```

Unfortunately WebStorm doesn't show the autocomplete for `myMethod` for `bam` class.

What should I do (except defining `foo` as class and extending it, which is not an option because of multi mixins that will be used)?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately `@mixin` + `@mixes` don't currently work for ES6, please follow [WEB-23997](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23997) for updates

Comment: :( thanx for the information. I hope it gets fixed.